# How to convert string in a tuple to an integer?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I scrape down stats that get put in a list that I later want to convert to a dictionary. The list looks like this:

```
 my_list = [('Appearances   ', '      32'),('Clean sheets   ', '      6'), etc,etc]
```

How do I convert the integers in the tuple to integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy, generally-applicable method would be to convert anything numeric (strings have a test for this) into an integer.  The slight trick to it is that the number string can't have spaces in it to check if it's numeric (but it *can* have them to convert to an integer).

So:

```
>>> listoftuples = [('Appearances   ', '      32'), ('Clean sheets   ', '      6')]
>>> [tuple(int(item) if item.strip().isnumeric() else item for item in group) for group in listoftuples]
>>> [('Appearances   ', 32), ('Clean sheets   ', 6)]
```

The advantage of this method is that it's not specific to your input.  It works fine if the integer is first, or if the tuples are different lengths, etc.

Comment: You bet.  You can change "else item" to "else item.strip()" if you don't want the extra spaces in your other items, but I left that out since you didn't specify.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = map(lambda x: [x[0], int(x[1].strip())], my_list)
```

Given an input list `my_list` of OP's specifications, return the resulting list with the second value stripped of whitespace and turned into an integer.

Comment: When I print my_list I just get <map at 0x122ed3128>, do you perhaps know why?

Comment: This is because function map includes an iterator, not a list itself. To print it like that, you will have to first convert it (for example by `list(map(...))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
    new_list = [(x[0], int(x[1].strip())) for x in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will convert the strings to integers. And, it will also create a dictionary using the list of tuples.

```
my_list = [
     ('Appearances   ', '      32'),
     ('Clean sheets   ', '      6')
]
d = dict()
for key, value in my_list:
    d[key.strip()] = int(value.strip())
print(d)
```

The above solution assumes each of the tuple in the list will have two elements `key` & `value`. All the first elements (keys) of the tuples are unique. And, the second elements (values) are strings that can be converted into integers.